¿Por qué no me funciona el autocompletado de netbeans para Java y Spring Boot 3?

Cuando intento autocompletar, aparece no suggestions. Así es si creo proyectos tanto de la web como directamente desde netbeans. Estoy usando la versión 24 de netbeans jdk 23, java 23 y spring boot 3

Lo mismo me ocurre a mi e incluso en instalaciones limpias, he probado con varias combinaciones jdk 17, con netbeans 17 y el plugin de spring boot 3.1, sin el plugin con el initializr, con netbenas 22 y java 21, y en todos me pasa lo mismo, solo en los proyectos de maven con spring boot, no funciona el auto completar y el go to declaration tampoco, ya no se que hacer, he hecho también lo que Iván ha aconsejado y nada.
Gracia

Hola Hee, verifica sin en: tools -> options seleccionas editor la pestaña code completion en el selector seleccionas java y en Completions Selectors for java tiene que figurar: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz. (incluido el punto final).

Verifica el JDK: Asegúrate de que NetBeans esté usando JDK 23. Ve a Herramientas > Opciones > Java y selecciona la versión correcta.
Reindexar Proyecto: Haz clic derecho en el proyecto y selecciona Limpiar y construir para regenerar los índices.
Complementos de Spring Boot: Ve a Herramientas > Complementos y asegúrate de tener los complementos de Spring Boot instalados.
Revisa el pom.xml: Asegúrate de que las dependencias estén bien definidas. Haz clic derecho y selecciona Actualizar Proyecto si usas Maven.
Limpiar la Caché: Borra la caché de NetBeans (en C:\Users\<TuUsuario>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\) y reinicia el IDE.
Prueba con otro JDK: Si el problema persiste, intenta usar JDK 17 o 20, ya que NetBeans puede no ser totalmente compatible con JDK 23.
Reinstalar NetBeans: Si nada de esto funciona, intenta hacer una instalación limpia de NetBeans.
¡Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema!
